# Combining string and expression interpolation

Tags: julia

I'm having trouble combining expression and string interpolation. I want to do something like this:

````
a = [:foo, :bar]
b = [:printfoo, :printbar]

for (str, fn) in zip(a,b)
  @eval begin
    """ 
    ```
    $fn()
    ```
    Prints $str.
    """
    $fn() = println("$str")
  end 
end
````

My desired output are two functions, one which might look, as typed, like

````
"""    
```
printfoo()
```
Prints foo.
"""
printfoo() = println("foo")
````

Instead, I get expressions that look like this (when I use `quote` rather than `@eval begin`):

````
```\n$(fn)()\n```\nPrints $(str).\n" # /home/..., line 12:
    printfoo() = begin  # /home/..., line 12:
            println("$(str)")
        end
````

I don't understand why using the same `$x` syntax, interpolation is performed as I want only outside of quoted (`"..."`) regions. I've tried some combinations of `$($x)` etc. but am missing some of the subtleties:

- `"$str"` -> `"$(str)"`
- `"$($str)"` -> `"$(foo)"`

What would map to `"foo"`?

Thanks.

Comment: Summary of longer answer below: `$("$str")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer seems to be `$(string(str))`.

The following version worked for me, but it took some tweaking to arrive at:

````
a = [:foo, :bar]
b = [:printfoo, :printbar]
for (str, fn) in zip(a,b)
  @eval begin
    $fn() = println($(string(str)))
    @doc $("```\n$fn()\n```\nPrints $str.\n") $fn
  end
end
````

One problem with the OP code was when the function bodies interpolated the variable during execution - this would cause `printfoo` to annoyingly print `bar`.

Comment: This is great. So I'm still trying to understand what makes `$("$str")` work but the other two "attempts" I note at the end fail. Any insight there? Thanks again.

Comment: The `$` operator has a different meaning in the quote context and in a string literal context. The outer `$` is in quote context, which tells Julia to evaluate immediately the "dollared" expression. The expression here is the string literal. The internal `$` is in string context, which substitutes the value of the `str` variable. But, I confess, macro thinking is of higher complexity than normal code.